# Citation Style Language: Modify the bibliography

Tags: citations, csl

I am using Zotero and want to change the bibliography slightly:

```
<group delimiter="">
  <text value=""/>
  <text variable="URL"/>
  <group prefix=". " suffix="">
    <text term="accessed" suffix=" "/>      
    <date variable="accessed">
       <date-part name="day" suffix=" "/> 
       <date-part name="month" form="" suffix=" "/>
       <date-part name="year" form=""/>
    </date>
  </group>
</group>
```

In this I suspect the name for the used term in bibliography is used (see below):

```
accessed 1 March 2017
```

This I want to change to upper case:

```
Accessed 1 March 2017
```

If I change the text term to "Accessed" I get an error

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can change `<text term="accessed" suffix=" "/>` to `<text term="accessed" text-case="capitalize-first" suffix=" "/>`. See http://docs.citationstyles.org/en/stable/specification.html#text-case.

Alternatively, you can use `<text value="Accessed" suffix=" "/>`, but generally the use of terms is preferred, because terms allow styles to more easily localize to different languages.

Comment: Also, it's not really related to your question, but your code has an issue with the `form=""`, which isn't allowed in CSL. I recommend using the CSL specification as reference when editing your code (see http://docs.citationstyles.org/en/stable/specification.html#date-part in particular), and using the CSL validator (http://validator.citationstyles.org/).